# how to use multiple processes with http

Tags: multithreading, http, go

How to make use of all CPUs and spawn a http process for each CPU?

Get num of CPUs

```
numCPU := runtime.NumCPU()
```

Start http

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your goal is just to have your *request-processing code* run on all CPU cores, `net/http` already starts a [goroutine](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements) (a vaguely thread-like thing with a Go-specific implementation) per connection, and Go arranges for `NumCPU` OS threads to run by default so that goroutines can be spread across all available CPU cores.

The `Accept` loop runs in a single goroutine, but the actual work of parsing requests and generating responses runs in one per connection.

Comment: In node.js and some other implementation (mostly multi-process not multi-threaded), accept runs on multiple "processes" / "threads". I thought that's what he meant but I could be totally off base here.

Comment: Just clarified that only the request processing is in goroutines (was writing that addition when I saw your comment!). Honestly not certain what they want, so leaving both out for them to see.

Comment: In nodejs you have to use `cluster` to spawn a new thread for each CPU.. but in Go you just need to set `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())` to achieve the same? Is that correct :)

Comment: @clarkk it's not exactly the same, there will only be one thread handling accepting new connections even with `runtime.GOMAXPROCS`, where in node it will be multiple threads (well, actual physical processes) handling accepting. check my answer and the link I posted there for nodejs-like behavior. Keep in mind that @DewyBroto is correct about unless your server is extremely loaded, you won't see any real benefit to multiple acceptors.

Comment: For people reading this now, the number of CPU cores is the default setting in go (>=1.5) and you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @NikolayDimitrov Thanks. I added that there are `NumCPU` OS threads and also removed an outdated source reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can't nativly, you have to write your own wrapper:

```
// copied from http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go#L1942
type tcpKeepAliveListener struct {
    *net.TCPListener
}

func (ln tcpKeepAliveListener) Accept() (c net.Conn, err error) {
    tc, err := ln.AcceptTCP()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    tc.SetKeepAlive(true)
    tc.SetKeepAlivePeriod(3 * time.Minute)
    return tc, nil
}

func ListenAndServe(addr string, num int) error {
    if addr == "" {
        addr = ":http"
    }
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            log.Println("listener number", i)
            log.Println(http.Serve(tcpKeepAliveListener{ln.(*net.TCPListener)}, nil))

            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    return nil
}

func main() {
    num := runtime.NumCPU()
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(num) //so the goroutine listeners would try to run on multiple threads
    log.Println(ListenAndServe(":9020", num))
}
```

Or if you use a recent enough Linux Kernel you can use the patch from http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.go.general/121122 and actually spawn multiple processes.